# c++ how to access variable from member function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, member

I have a problem. I want to operate with single element of an array, which is generated in member function, but it doesn´t work. Here is my code:

```
    using namespace std;

    class Example
    {
    public:
        int *pole;
        void generate_pole();
    };

    void Example::generate_pole()
    {
        int *pole = new int [10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            pole[i] = i;
        }
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        Example reference;

        reference.generate_pole();

        cout << reference.pole[1] << endl;          //there is the problem

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

How can I get an access to the element? And where is the real problem? Thank you!

Comment: You are shadowing the member variable here: `int *pole = new int [10];` change that part to `pole = new int [10];`

Comment: And turn on your compiler warnings!  `gcc -Wall -Wextra`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *pole = new int [10];` is creating an identically named variable `pole` in local scope. This is *shadowing* the member variable.

A fix, drop the `int*` from the errant line: `pole = new int [10];`

That said, I'd be inclined to use a *constructor* to set the member variable in this case: certainly you should initialise `pole` to `nullptr` by default. This is so you can `delete[] pole` in a *destructor* when an instance of your class goes out of scope. Else your code will leak memory like a colander leaks water.

An other way would be to use `std::vector<int> pole;` and let the C++ standard library take care of all the memory for you.

Comment: It won't compile, remove the * in front of `pole = new int [10];`

Comment: Ha ha. We'll publish jointly!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you shadow pole's name in the scope of the function by redeclaring it. leave the `int *` in front of pole behind, in `generate_pole`, and it should work.

An example for shadowing:

```
int i = 0; // i is 0
std::cout << "before scope: " << i << std::endl; // prints 0
{ 
    int i = 1; 
    std::cout << "inside scope: " << i << std::endl; // prints 1
}
std::cout << "behind scope: " << i << std::endl; // prints 0
```